# curl upload file -T

Tags: http, curl, file-upload

I get the error `curl: Can't open 'files=@1.txt'!` when trying to run code:

```
curl -v -XPOST -k -H "Accept: application/json" -T "files=@1.txt"  https://192.168.1.102/
```

any suggestion on how to pass the text file's name properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-T` is for PUT and wants a file name only:

```
curl -T 1.txt https://192.168.1.102/
```

You seem to want to POST a file? If you want it sent "plainly", you probably want:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" --data-binary @1.txt https://192.168.1.102/
```

If you want to instead send  the file as a multipart formpost, you might do it similar to:

```
curl -F files=@1.txt https://192.168.1.102/
```

Comment: so if I want to use -T, how can I specify what's the name of the attribute? without that I get the error: "The current URL, <code>resources/1.txt</cod"e>, didn't match any of these. "

Comment: `-T`  makes a PUT request. There are no "attributes" then, and no names for them either.

Comment: in that case I need to make a post request because I need to specify the name of it. basically I'm making a new 'resource' in the website which can have different files as input.

Comment: the problem is that -F gives me "Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!"

Comment: No, you get that warning  because you try to use -F together with some other option that you can't combine it with...